# How to store neighbours of a cell in a gird into a priority queue

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, dijkstra

Say I have a 4 by 4 grid, so 16 cells. Each cell contains a value between 1,5. eg.

```
     0 1 2 3
     _ _ _ _
0 - |2|1|3|2|
1 - |1|3|5|1|
2 - |5|2|1|4|
3 - |2|4|2|1|
```

Now I know that I need to use Dijkstra algorithm. Also to optimise this I need to use a Priority queue.

My aim is to find the shortest sum of each cell to a destination. The source can be random on the grid and the destination as well. (i.e. not always top left to bottom right).

I have worked with graphs that use adjacent matrix. However with this grid is it wise to create an adjacent matrix? i.e. set all fields to infinity that aren't neighbours. What would be the most sufficient way of inserting cells into a priority queue? Would it be {(row,col), distance}?

Just to clarify from my understanding, The priority queue will store the best path? So the cell and the accumulative distance. Because, Dijstra's algorithm uses BFS which will search all neighbours for the shortest distance in this case.

Comment: Which part of replacing the regular queue used by BFS with a priority queue is troubling you?

Comment: @Andreas - So if I have a starting cell, say (1,1) how do I store this into a priority queue such that the value is (1,1), and they key is the distance. I'm not sure how to insert a tuple into a priority queue. i WANT {(1,1), 0} for the first index and say {(1,2),2} for the next cell after doing a BFS

Comment: So create a class with 3 fields, make it `Comparable` on the distance, and insert into priority queue. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Andreas why do we need to create a class? Sorry if that sounds dumb

Comment: Because you want to store objects with 3 values into the priority queue, and you need a priority comparison implementation for the object, so the simplest way to accomplish that is to create a class for the purpose, and make the distance field the *natural order* of the object. How else did you intend to store the `{(1,2),2}` values?

Comment: @Andreas I didnt know how thats why I asked :) I see what you mean. I also have to create a comparator class that order the queue too? Also would ```PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue();``` be the right way to initialse and add {(r,c},d} to that.

Comment: Make a `Node` a class that has 3 fields (row, column, value) and implements `Comparable`. Then use Use `PriorityQueue<Node>`.

Comment: @C0der Okay cheers

Comment: @C0der When creating the comparator class it implements <node> correct? And how to a get it to compare against the distance parameter in node object

Comment: I guess you mean    `Comparable<Node>`

Comment: @C0der yes, then do I have to create a method in Node to get distance and call that on the o1 and o2 to compare in the comparator class?

Comment: You want to compare nodes based on their value : `public int compareTo(Node other) { 
  return Integer.compare(value, other.value);
 }`

Comment: @C0der So in the node class I have created a getColumn,getRow,getDist. Then in my comparator class i have ```public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) { return o1.getDistance() - o2.getDistance(); } ```. Does that look right?

Comment: To shorten the process I posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a 'Node' a class that has 3 fields (row, column, distance) and implements Comparable. Then use Use `PriorityQueue<Node>`:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        pq.add(new Node(2, 3, 12));
        pq.add(new Node(0, 9, 1));
        pq.add(new Node(4, 0, 8));

        System.out.println(pq.poll().getDistance()); //prints 1
    }
}

class Node  implements Comparable<Node>{

    private final int row, col, distance;

    public Node(int row, int col, int value) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        distance = value;
    }

    int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node other) {
        return Integer.compare(distance, other.distance);
    }
}
```

Alternatively set a `Comperator` to the priority queue so `Node` does not have to implement `Comparable`:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Node::compare);
        pq.add(new Node(2, 3, 12));
        pq.add(new Node(0, 9, 1));
        pq.add(new Node(4, 0, 8));

        System.out.println(pq.poll().getDistance()); //prints 1
    }
}

class Node{

    private final int row, col, distance;

    public Node(int row, int col, int value) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        distance = value;
    }

    int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public static int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getDistance(), o2.getDistance());
    }
}
```

You could also use a lambda expression to set a comperator:

`PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((o1,o2)->Integer.compare(o1.getDistance(), o2.getDistance()));`

All three options are valid.

Comment: *"set a cooperator"* Did you mean "give a `Comparator`"?

Comment: @C0der Thanks! Does one work better then the other?